# Selecting a random string from a file while having fixed array offset

Tags: php

I'm trying to select a random line from the first 5 lines of a file that contains multiple strings.

The problem is some of the files have less than 5 lines.

```
for example i have files that contain:
string 1
string 2

other files contain:
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
string 5
string 6
string 7
```

My code below works fine with files that contain more than 5 lines. However with files that contain less than that, I'm getting a blank/empty output/result in some cases. is there a way to force it to ignore blank output? or should i count file lines and make an if statement based on the line count? or should i use array_filter?

```
$file = file('/home/file.txt');
$selected_tag = $file[rand(0, 4)];
```

Comment: `or should i count file lines and make an if statement based on the line count? ` Seems like a good idea to me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$file = file('/home/file.txt');
$selected_tag = implode(PHP_EOL,array_splice($file,5));
$result = implode(PHP_EOL,$file);
echo $result;
?>
```